# Error when connecting to remote virtual machine via ssh

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi I am having trouble connecting to the GCP VM via ssh, for some reason I can connect via `ssh -i gpc juand@34.125.13.53`  but when I create the config file with this configuration

```
Host corelogic-vm
     HostName 34.125.13.53
     User juand
     IdentityFile C:/Users/juand/.ssh/gpc
```

I get this error when I type `ssh corelogic-vm`

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname corelogic-vm: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Is your file here? C:\Users\your_username\.ssh\config

Comment: @TaronQalashyan you were right it was in another folder, if you want to answer with that answer ill accept your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your file here? C:\Users\your_username.ssh\config